# How can i get specific user data from firestore in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

So the problem is, when i'm trying to get the details by using `forEach` function it gives me all the user's details which is available on the firestore..let me explain with code:

Here is my code for getting details in Profile Page :

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

class ProfilePage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        profiledata : null
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        firestore.collection('profiledata')
            // .doc("JgT2LyOB4jqhMv9YMgrh")
            .get()
            
             .then((snapshot) => {
                const profiledata  = []
                snapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                    const data = doc.data();
                    profiledata.push(data);
                }
                )
                this.setState({profiledata :  profiledata})
             })
             }
             
            render(){
        return(
            <div className='profile'>
                <h1>User</h1>
                {
                    this.state.profiledata && 
                        this.state.profiledata.map( profiledata => {
                            return(
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        First Name : {String(profiledata.firstname)}
                                        Last Name : {String(profiledata.lastname)}
                                        Company Name : {String(profiledata.companyname)}
                                                                        
                                        </p>
                                </div>
                                
                            )
                        })
                }
                </div>
        )
    }export default ProfilePage;
```

Here is my Output :

There are three user data in my firestore collection and it gives me in profilepage, now the problem is how can i get the specific user details??

[image]

Any suggestions?? How can i do that?

Comment: Can you also share the structure of your database?

Answer (score 0):

In your database structure inside the profiledata collections there are few docs. Therefore if you want to get a specific profile data you have to get the document id. To retrieve the document id you can use doc.id.